# Explain the output of the following Java program

Tags: java, inheritance

```
package com.test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new B().toString());
    }
}


package com.test;

class A {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}

package com.test;

public class B extends A {

}
```

This program gives output com.test.B but if I change toString method of class A to

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Then it print hello. why?

Comment: Why does the output surprise you?

Comment: I'd wager good money that the reason the output changed is because you changed it.

Comment: Ahem, you change the method to print "hello" and then you are surprised that it prints that? The secret behind this is called method overwriting.

Comment: What's the question?  You tell it to print "blah" it prints "blah".  You tell it to print "foop" and it prints "foop".

Comment: I think the issue the OP is having is that it was printing that it is a `B` and now it's printing `hello` but the method is in `A`. I would start with [the basics of inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to understand.

Comment: No one expects the spanish inheritance ... i guess

Comment: I thought that in case `new B().toString` would print `com.test.A`

Comment: No.  `this.getClass()` returns the actual class of the object (the most specific class), not the class in which that line of code was written.  Otherwise, there wouldn't be much point in using it.

Comment: +1 to all answers thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first function call when the method is:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getClass().getName();
}
```

Since this method is invoked from the B class instance then `this.getClass()` refers to `B` class object. Thus `getName()` function prints

> com.test.B

If the same function would have been invoke by creating `A` class object then output would have been,

> com.test.A

And when you change the `toString` function to this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "hello";
}
```

it will return `hello`, as you have returned the `hello` as the return value.

Now if you really want to understand the `@Override` then add this code to class B and in A class let the function returning `hello` be there

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return this.getClass().getName();
}
```

Try the above code, and invoke the `toString` function from class A and class B instance object. Then it will be more clear what `@Override` does  and how it works

Answer (score 1):

In this `toString` method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getClass().getName();
}
```

you are returning [this.getClass().getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29), which returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class, primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object, as a String.

And when you change the `toString` to this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "hello";
}
```

its returning `hello`, because you have `"hello"` as the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're calling `toString()` on an instance of `B` and printing that. `B` has no `toString()` of its own, but inherits it from `A`. The `toString()` defined in `A` returns the name of the class. So when `B` is using it, the name of the class is `com.test.B`, which is what's returned.
If you change the implementation in `A` to return "hello" instead, that's what it will return.

You may have been expecting the first version to print `com.test.A`, so I'll explain why that doesn't happen.
It's not that `B` asks `A` "what's the result of `toString()`, `B` asks `A` "what do I have to do to get the result of `toString()`. In the first case, `A` tells `B` "just return your (class) name", while in the second case, `A` tells `B` "just say 'hello'".